# How to run multiple agents (given on runtime) simultaneously with Jenkins Declarative Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline, jenkins-agent

I'm running a Jenkins Job on multiple platforms selected manually at runtime. Having multi-select Active Choices Parameter named "Platforms" for the relevant nodes.

I'm using the following code in Jenkins scripted pipeline:

```
def labels=Platforms.toString().split(",").collect{"\'" + it + "\'"}
    def builders=[:]
    
    for (label in labels) {
        builders[label] = {
                node(label) {
                    stage ('Stage 1') {
                        sh 'hostname'
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    parallel builders
```

How can I accomplish the same thing in Declarative Pipeline?
The agents are selected randomly by the user at runtime.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found my answer here:
[Running same Jenkins job on multiple agents in parallel in declarative pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930433/running-same-jenkins-job-on-multiple-agents-in-parallel-in-declarative-pipeline)
Thanks to user 'np2807'.
My code is now looking like this:

```
def labels=Platforms.toString().split(",").collect{"\'" + it + "\'"}

def generateStage(nodeLabel) {
    return {
        stage("Runs on ${nodeLabel}") {
            node(nodeLabel) {
                stage("Stage 1") {
                   script {
                        echo "Running on ${nodeLabel}"
                        sh 'hostname'
                      }
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}

def parallelStagesMap = labels.collectEntries {
    ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
}

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('non-parallel stage') {
            steps {
                echo 'This stage will be executed first.'
            }
        }
        stage('parallel stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel parallelStagesMap
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```